# ex.getClass().getCanonicalName() not giving exception class name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I am trying to handle exception in Spring boot using `@ControllerAdvice` . I am handling all type of exception using `Exception.class`and giving json response.

When I am adding `HTTPStatus status` in `handleAllExceptionMethod()` I am getting following response when `null pointer exception is occurs`

But in that JSON response I am expecting `"error" : "java.lang.NullPointerException"` which I am throwing from service class `throw new NullPointerException("Null values are not allowed")`

Before adding `HTTPStatus status` in `handleAllExceptionMethod()` I was getting expected result. I added that in method for getting status value in `status` filed.

Can any one please tell me why its happening like this?

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptionMethod(Exception ex,WebRequest requset,HttpStatus status) {

        ExceptionMessage exceptionMessageObj = new ExceptionMessage();

        exceptionMessageObj.setStatus(status.value());
        exceptionMessageObj.setMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        exceptionMessageObj.setError(ex.getClass().getCanonicalName());     
        exceptionMessageObj.setPath(((ServletWebRequest) requset).getRequest().getServletPath());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionMessageObj, new HttpHeaders(),status);     
    }
}
```

When I am getting Null pointer exception This is JSON result

[image]

Comment: What is the "expected result"? What do you get instead?

Comment: I am expecting `error` as `NullPointerException` insted of `error` as `Internal server error`

Comment: You are sure that error is really Internal Server Error? That sounds more like the HttpStatus Description. How do you verify that error is set to Internal Server Error?

Comment: I added `HTTP status` in method for `.setStatus(status.value());` why its reflecting in error?